# Markdown to HTML/Latex: Is there a way to make Figure Like in markdown?

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to make that Images, Tables, Equations, Theorems, Code, Quotes be surround around Figures Tags when I produce a HTML or Latex Document, and in the process way to indexed them... 
And well the documentation si a little bit ambiguose on how to do that, I've tried to think of a way to do a filter (in python) for it, but, I can't Find the appropriate tree elements for the filter.

Currently my only workaround is to scrape the HTML that it generates, to apply the correct (desired) structure.

I'm Ussing Katex, and Highlight.Js for the math and code. 
Any help or ideas?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref and possibly https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3177

Comment: I've Tried that, but it doesn't give me the desired format, I was thinking on creating my own format and put it in fenced_code_attributes, and then "parse" the fenced code to format it.

Comment: I'd go for a [fenced div](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) then instead of the fenced code block...

Comment: I'll Try that, I just read the documentation, and I think It kind of fixes the issue.